# How many Januarys in a date range

Tags: c#, date

I have a date range (a date and number of months) and I want to count the number of Januarys in that date range.

For example, ending at `5/2015` and going back 20 months there are 2 Januarys: `1/2015` and `1/2014`.

Comment: Please make an effort first.  Even if your code does not work, share what you have and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int currentMonth = 5;
int monthsBack = 20;

int numberOfJans = (int) Math.Floor((monthsBack - currentMonth) / 12.0) + 1;
```

This is maths, not C#.

Answer (score 0):

Count months between sample

```
        DateTime dateEnd = Convert.ToDateTime("01/08/2015"); 
        int monthsBack = 24;

        DateTime dateStart = dateEnd.AddMonths(-monthsBack);

        int janCount = 0;
        for (DateTime dd = dateStart; dd < dateEnd; dd = dd.AddMonths(1))
        {
            if (dd.Month == 1) //if jan
                janCount += 1;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(dateStart.ToShortDateString() +" to "+ dateEnd.ToShortDateString()
                        + Environment.NewLine +Environment.NewLine +
                        janCount.ToString()
                        );
```

Comment: There's no need to ToString() the Month in your if statment.  dd.Month == 1 will suffice.